# Why a NuGet package is uninstalling itself after some time?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to install this NuGet package: `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager`, for my .NET Core project. But after few seconds after install the package is uninstalling by itself. Why?
Only if I uncheck this two checkboxes: [image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/media/restore-01-autorestoreoptions.png), then this package, and I guess all others are not uninstalling but their selfs.

Comment: What does the output say? If not already done, install it via the NuGet Package Manager Console, it'll give you log output.

Comment: @Squirrelkiller is installing successfully, but after few seconds is uninstalling by itself without any messages to log.

Comment: Then how do you know it uninstalled? Does the .csproj or package.json get changed?

Comment: i just installed that package to a .net core console app project and it got installed. I would recommend trying to install that package to a new net core project to isolate the issue.

Comment: If you have the csproj open in an editor tab, you might be hitting [this issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/443877/assembly-reference-is-removed-from-project-after-r.html) which will hopefully be fixed in the next VS2019 preview.

Comment: @EduardStefanescu, does this issue happens to all your .NET core projects in VS 2019? Do you did something before this package auto be uninstalled? If your VS 2019 is not the latest version, please try to upgrade it or repair it to test this issue again.

Comment: I fixed the problem unchecking those two checkboxes from that screenshot, after that I restart VisualStudio and checking them again. Now the problem seems to be fixed.

Comment: @EduardStefanescu, so glad to hear that your issue is solved, please add a answer with your solution, that will also help other community members who meet the same or similar issues in the future, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem unchecking those two checkboxes from that screenshot, after that I restart VisualStudio and checking them again. Now the problem seems to be fixed.